# Is running a database in Kubernetes an antipattern?

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, architecture, cloud

Let's say we are running some services in a Kubernetes cluster and one of them requires a PostgreSQL instance, expected to persist data reliably. Should the DB live in the cluster or be configured separately?

Imagine that the DB is deployed in the cluster. This probably means one of the following:

1. We need a process for migrating the data to another node in case the current one goes down. This sounds like a non-trivial task. Or:
2. The node where the DB lives has to be treated in a special way. Horizontal scaling must be constrained to the other nodes and the cluster ceases to be homogeneous. This might be seen as a design flaw, going against the spirit of maintaining disposable, replaceable containers.

Point (1) applies only to self-managed clusters where all the storage we have at our disposal is tied to machines where the nodes run. If we are using a managed cloud, we can use persistent volume claims and a new instance can pick up the data automatically. Still, this means that if the node with the DB is removed, we will suffer a database downtime until a new instance comes up. So point (2) remains valid also for managed K8s offerings.

Therefore I can well understand the argument for keeping the DB outside of Kubernetes. What would some counterarguments look like? There are a lot of official helm charts for various DBs which suggests that people keep their DBs in Kubernetes clusters after all.

Happy to learn some critical thoughts!

Comment: 1. doesn't apply in self-managed clusters either, where you will typically use something like [ceph](https://ceph.io/en/) or other distributed storage solution. You did not explain why you believe 2. to be true. Running stateful services in k8s is a lot more work and consideration that stateful, but it's definitely not an antipattern.

Comment: Thank you, @jordanm, I'll research ceph. About (2): the PV cannot be used by 2 DB instances at the same time. If the current DB pod were to be removed due to the cluster's horizontal scaling, the PV would have to be detached from the pod and attached to a new pod in another node, before that new pod could start. This would constitute a downtime, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an anti-pattern. It is just difficult to implement and manage.

**Point 1**

- In a self hosted cluster also you can have persistent volume storage provisioned though GlusterFS and CEPH. So, you don't always have to use ephemeral storage. So, Point 1 is not fully valid.
- The DBs are generally created as a [statefulsets](https://devopscube.com/deploy-postgresql-statefulset/), where every instance gets its own copy of data.

**Point 2**

- When your DB cluster horizontally scales, the 'init' container of the new DB pod or a CRD provided by the DB needs to register the 'secondary' DB pod so it becomes the part of your dB cluster
- A [statefulset](https://devopscube.com/deploy-postgresql-statefulset/) needs to also run as a [headless service](https://chamszamouri.medium.com/why-stateful-applications-in-k8s-need-a-headless-service-20d3db993872) so the IPs of each endpoint is also known all the time for cluster healthcheck and primary->secondary data sync and to elect a new primary selection in case the primary node goes down
- So, as long as the new pods register themselves to the DB cluster, you will be okay to run your db workload inside a kubernetes cluster

Further reading: https://devopscube.com/deploy-postgresql-statefulset/

Comment: Ad 1. Thank you, I'll look closer at GlusterFS and CEPH.
Ad 2. Only one instance of the DB can access the persistent volume at any given time. Let's say that A and B are DB pods. A is about to be removed due to its node removal and B is the successor. The sequence will be: detach the PV from A, attach it to B, start the process in B. This constitutes the DB downtime. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: No, Dbs are deployed as stateful sets in a primary secondary clusters model. So, every pod has gets its own persistent volume. When a node goes down, pod running on that node will also go down with its volume. But the cluster continues to function. So, when a new pod comes up on a new node and joins the cluster, the secondary pod will get a new persistent volume and the data will be synced to it. This may take time but that's the reason you start with more than one pod to begin with for redundancy.

Comment: Yes, you can have "more than one pod to begin with for redundancy", e.g. for Postgres you can set up another instance in standby mode for HA. However this means that if you simply want to run a single instance of Postgres, you cannot do that in Kubernetes, even though outside of it you can do so quite reasonably. And if you go with Kubernetes, you will have to use 2 instances from the start. Is this part of what you originally meant by "It is just difficult to implement and manage"?

Comment: No, setting up and managing your own persistent storage is difficult.